Ampere-Maxwell Law for Resistor in AC circuit
Let's say we have a resistor ($R$) attached to a sinusoidal voltage source ($V = V_0 \sin{\omega t}$) so that we get a changing sinusoidal electric field inside the resistor. We construct an Amperian loop around one of the wires connecting to the resistor and attach a flat surface to it, we get for the magnetic field around it (assuming 0 resistance wires): $$ \oint B \cdot dl = \mu_0 I_{enc}, $$  if we now take a surface for the same loop which cuts through the resistor we get:
$$ \oint B \cdot dl = \mu_0 I_{enc} + \mu_0 \epsilon_0\frac{d \Phi_E}{dt} $$ since $\left(\frac{d \Phi_E}{dt} \neq 0 \right) $ inside the resistor. We end up with 2 different values for $B$ depending on the surface chosen which seems to contradict Ampere-Maxwell's law. What am I missing?

The "ideal resistor" is just what it says: an idealization. Typically we can get adequately accurate solutions to circuits by assuming that resistors are ideal and have no capacitance, but that doesn't mean it is precisely true.
If $\frac{d\Phi_E}{dt}$ is non-zero in the body of the resistor, it means that charges (equal and opposite) are building up at or in the two ends of the resistor.
If that is true, it means that the conduction current through the resistor is not in fact precisely identical to the current in the wires connecting to the resistor, and we shouldn't expect it to be.
As the answer by naturallyinconsistent says, this leads to a phase shift in the resistor current, as it should if the resistor has a parallel parasitic capacitance, which your logic shows it must have if it has nonzero physical length. (And this shows why one of the important components of the lumped circuit approximations is the assumption that the components have zero physical size --- because this approximation reduces this effect to zero)

But why does the Ampere-Maxwell law correctly predict the B field in the case of a capacitor but fails to do so with the resistor? And what is the actual value of the B field around the resistor?

@Loop, the $I_{enc}$ in your two equations are not the same. Not all of the conduction current in the wires goes through the (physical, distributed) resistor. Some is used to charge and discharge the stored charge on the resistor terminals, and becomes displacement current.

that actually makes a lot of sense. Which means the integral of the B field is actually $\mu_0 I_{enc}$ where $I_{enc}$ is the current in the wire. Thanks for your input!

I think this is merely a reshuffling of contributions that is not going to be a big deal.
Before we get there, let's review Ohm's law, which is typically remembered as
$$\tag1V=IR$$
If a wire or resistor has length $L$ and cross-sectional area $A$, the definitions of electric field $\left|\vec E\right|=\frac VL$ and the current density $\left|\vec\jmath\right|=\frac IA$ converts Ohm's law into another form
$$\tag2\vec\jmath=\sigma\vec E\qquad\bigvee\qquad\vec E=\rho\vec\jmath$$
where $\sigma=\frac L{RA}=\frac1\rho$
Inserting Ohm's Law into Ampère–Maxwell law, we obtain
$$\tag3\oint_{\partial S}\vec{\vec B}\cdot\vec{\mathrm d\ell}=\mu_0\iint_S\left[\vec\jmath+\varepsilon_0\partial_t\left(\rho\vec\jmath\right)\right]\cdot\vec{\vec{\mathrm d^2A}}$$
Now, if you look at this, you notice that it is linear in the magnitude of $\vec\jmath$, and for constant $\rho$ and that $\varepsilon_0$ is a tiny constant, what this does is insert a slight phase shift to the integral. You also do expect a phase shift anyway, since in AC circuits you have waves propagating down the circuit, the $\vec\jmath$ at different points may be phase shifted a bit, and so this should be perfectly fine.
